# Opencart where are extension status and position set?

Tags: php, opencart

Quick question about open cart, where are extension status and position set? I can see in the code

```
$postion = $this->config->get($extension . '_position');
```

and also

```
'status'      => $this->config->get($extension . '_status')
```

However I can't see where these are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, look into your  extension file ( for example 'payment/free_checkout.php') and search for something like that

```
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting( 'free_checkout', $this->request->post);
```

This is where settings stored into database ( you can go deeper into setting model, if you want )

After that, open admin/index.php and look at lines 38 - 48. 
You can see, system gets data from database and store data into config object.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I can see that the setting table is used to store information about the extension, but I can't see where the position and enabled/disabled status is stored?

Comment: I didn't find any position mentions (i check last opencart version). But if you want find status. Look into extension form (For example payment/free_checkout.php). You'll find field  called  extensionname_status (selectbox "free_checkout_status"). When you send this form to the server, it will store it into database ($this->model_setting_setting->editSetting ... // see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Opencart Positions are used by Modules. They are set in admin unders extensions/modules. When you click save - it saves them to the database table oc_settings under the modulename_module

When Opencart is launched - in INDEX.php there is this code

```
// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0' OR store_id = '" . (int)$config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY store_id ASC");

foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
    if (!$setting['serialized']) {
        $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
    } else {
        $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
    }
}
```

it creates the config - a massive array of all the settings for the current store id.

Afterwards the position controllers (column_left.php, column_right.php, content_top.php and content_bottom.php) go through the extensions in the table oc_extension and finds all the modules that will need to be shown.

then it goes through this massive array CONFIG and collects the settings for these modules - this all is stored in a array $module_data

then the controller uses these settings to basicly launch every controller of the module that should be shown. It passes the controller route and $settings for every module in a foreach loop and in result gets a render of the modules.

You can access the config anywhere in the php file - it can be another controller, a model or even tpl file.

```
$this->config->get(...)
```

If you want - you can go directly to the databes oc_settings and get the data from there with these functions

```
$this->load->model('setting/setting'); // remeber to always load the model.
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting( 'free_checkout', $this->request->post);
```

Hope this helps.

Also you can use this module to expend the number of positions for your opencart SUPER easy
[Extra positions Unlimited](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&token=extension_id=14467)